# array in url mvc 4 api

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to call an API from and application. I need to pass an array to the api. I have read it was possible by typing this:

```
string url = http://urltje?ids=1&ids=2
```

This would have resulted in an array of ints with 1and 2 in it.

Now I'm working with mvc 4 and it seems not be working anymore. How can I do this now?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add `[FromUri]` on your get method ?

```
GetUrls([FromUri] int[] ids)
```

Comment: If I add that attribute, my variable ids still is 'null'

Comment: It works, ensure your Get method is called, the url should be something like /yourcontroller/geturls?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3

Comment: was my mistake... was using seperate classes in my api to get the data and provided the wrong method with the attribute... works just fine!